# Retraining or Continuing Training

Tags: python, tensorflow

Ive started experimenting with tensorflow lately and there is one thing I'm not quite sure i get right:
  If i have a set of training data, train the model  on it for N number of epochs and than use `model.save("Multi_stage_test.model")` to save the model.

After running the program again with the same training data and with the previously trained model loaded with `model=load_model("Multi_stage_test.model")`. Am I continuing to train the model (the 1 epoch of the training session is a N+1 epoch for the model) or am I retraining the model (the 1 epoch of the training session is a 1 epoch for the model)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load your model before the training instructions, then you are continuing to train the same model. Tensorflow will just load the pre-trained weights of your model and continue updating them during the new training session.

Comment: The model is loaded before the training instructions. I'm asking Because Ive noticed that when i run the program again after a previous training session. There is a "gap" in performance. For example 1session 100 epoch:"loss: 0.3514 - acc: 0.8316 - val_loss: 1.5131 - val_acc: 0.5909" 2session 1 epoch:"loss: 0.5916 - acc: 0.6616 - val_loss: 0.7173 - val_acc: 0.5606" And i don't understand why is that happening

Comment: Hum weird... are you using the same learning rate for all the epochs ? And which optimizer ?

Comment: My optimizer: `tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6)`
as for the learning rate the answer will be no because I have this: `reduce_lr=  ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='val_loss', factor=0.0005, patience=3, min_lr=0.001, verbose=1)`

Comment: The decay is applied every epoch. That means that you are not using the same learning rate on the 100th epoch of the first session and on the 1st epoch of the 2nd session. That's why the loss might increase a bit on the first retraining epoch !